# Static file server by Golang for serving Vue.js app

Tags: go, vue.js

I want to create a simple file server in `Go` for serving static files of a `Vue.js` app.

By default `Vue.js` has its own runner using `npm run dev` or `npm run build`.

The point is when I run `Vue.js` app by its own tooling system, it falls back `404 error` to `index.html`. So `Vue-router` can handle the rest.

How can I handle that in `Go`?

I tried `httprouter` and its `NotFound` method as the documentation mentioned, but it only serves static files if there is no defined route on the `Router`.

Comment: Have you tried https://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router.ServeFiles?

Comment: @mkopriva As the documentation said:
"Internally a http.FileServer is used, therefore http.NotFound is used instead of the Router's NotFound handler."

So it will return `404` error code in my case.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a folder structure like below

[image]

You can use the following golang code to serve the static files. I've added an extra api to show how we could have that as well. [gorilla-mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) is used for URL routing.

I've taken the built distribution to serve via golang. And `index.html`looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=static/normalize.css>
  <title>vue-spa</title>
  <link href=./static/css/app.6fde27bf4e24b3395514fd5ee0329156.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=app></div>
  <script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/manifest.6fd2c38fc83e93a893ff.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/vendor.bc5a61acb9e2b4c6e037.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/app.c8f0b049292d256d1e93.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that it's base for static files is `./static`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
    "log"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    // It's important that this is before your catch-all route ("/")
    api := r.PathPrefix("/api/").Subrouter()
    api.HandleFunc("/users", GetUsersHandler).Methods("GET")
    // Serve static assets directly.
    r.PathPrefix("/static").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist/")))
    // Catch-all: Serve our JavaScript application's entry-point (index.html).
    r.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(IndexHandler("dist/index.html"))


srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r),
        Addr:    "127.0.0.1:8088",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}

func IndexHandler(entrypoint string) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, entrypoint)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func GetUsersHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "id": "123",
        "timeStamp": time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339),
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
        return
    }
    w.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: Thank’s, is there any workaround to do this without using gorilla package?

Comment: @amirhosseinab which package do you want to use in this case?

Comment: httprouter or no third party packages, and use net/http package. Is it possible at all?

Comment: httprouter is a third party library

Comment: Yes, I know that. I’m ok with that package.

Comment: The missing link that is unique to Vue is solved by this line: r.PathPrefix("/static")... Nice help.

Answer (score 2):

**This is how I serve our Vue.js single page app**

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
// we have a single page application
// we need to catch all routes and redirect them to the app's entrypoing (index.html)
wwwFiles := http.Dir("./static/www")
wwwPath := "/"
wwwHandler := http.FileServer(wwwFiles)
wwwRouter := router.PathPrefix(wwwPath).Handler(http.StripPrefix(wwwPath, wwwHandler))
// define a Matcher host in case you want to use the '/' path to serve other content
// the regex is for eventual dev/qa/... environments
wwwRouter.Host("www{_:|[a-z]*}.my.app")
// redirect all requests starting with '/' to the 'www' path which index.html will catch
wwwRouter.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, wwwFiles)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this little package that mimics parts of the standard `fs.go` functionality and use it.

https://github.com/amirhosseinab/sfs